# Awesome font instead of image in url

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

Well, I have this kind of url

```
<a href="#" onclick='window.open("https://www.facebook.com/DavarashviliClinic/");return false;'>
  <img src="http://ddc.websitedesign.ge/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/f.png" alt="Facebook" />
</a>
```

and want to change the facebook png image with awesome font icon code

```
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
```

How to do this here in top blue header [my site](http://ddc.websitedesign.ge/) ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace the `img` with the `i` and specify the required **Font Awesome** class.

You can change the color by adding `style="color:white;"` or you can use the CSS selector

```
a i{
   color: white
}
```

---

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<a href="#" onclick='window.open("https://www.facebook.com/DavarashviliClinic/");return false;'>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook" style="color:white;"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it's blue instead of white and I can't see it. How to change the color? And where I must add this url? <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: @Merkucio : Thats the reference Font Awesome icons, add it inside `<head>` section

Comment: @Merkucio : Yes, if you have already linked the required files.

Comment: I didn't but wordpress theme did, I think.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110288/discussion-between-pugazh-and-merkucio).